# Kivy add icon to Button

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to replace the text in a Button with an icon in Kivy 191. I tried it inside an ActionBar widget with ActionButton like this :

```
ActionBar:
    ActionView:
        ActionButton:
            icon: "path-to-image"
```

and it worked perfectly. But when I try to do the same on a regular Button:

```
Button:
    icon: "path-to-image"
```

nothing happens. The button stays blank, and if I add text with the icon property still present, the text appears, but still no icon. Am I doing something wrong? if so, how can I fix it?

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr It worked, but i'm having a hard time positioning the rect in the exact middle of the Button. I tried "pos: (self.pos[0] + self.pos[0] + self.width)/2 to get the center x of the Button, but failed.

Comment: `pos: self.pos[0] + self.width/2 - <image width>/2`, same thing for height.

Comment: Button doesn't have an icon property. Try `background_normal`.